# play mov file format in android studio using intent

Tags: android, android-intent

In my android app, I cannot play mov file format video file in with intent and it shows (Failed to play video) in app and in logcat, it shows Exception occurred:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URI for .mov file format

Comment: post your code here

Comment: Intent videoIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        videoIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        videoIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(finalToLoad), "video/*");
        context.startActivity(videoIntent);

Comment: The `mov` file format is not supported by Android (well, you know, it's an **Apple** media format). https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats.html

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(videoPath));
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(videoPath), "video/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

Please make sure , your path is correct

Comment: yes, my path is correct , i can play .mp4 file except .mov file. Is there any other way to play .mov format file using intent?

Comment: Then i think your device does not contain any application that will play .mov format

Comment: yes, my device is samsung s6 edge , android 7+. Some suggested me to transcode .mov to .mp4 . but i can't find any code or library to .mov url to .mp4 url in android studio.

Answer (score 0):

First get .mov (quick time) file from intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(videoPath));
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(videoPath), "video/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

and use

```
implementation 'com.devbrackets.android:exomedia:4.3.0'
```

instead of Default VideoView of Android. Method of using this videoview is same like default android videoview.